# Can a UI control be both an Outlet and Action?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

I am working on one of the cs193p assignments. They asked to add a segmented control to the UI of the assignment app.

Certain things needed to happen when the user selected different options on the segmented switch. Which indicates it needs to be an Action.

At the same time, when the user interacts with another UI element in the app, the segmented switch needed to be disabled. This indicates the switch also needs to be an outlet, so that we can have a reference to it in our controller as we need to modify its state even when the user is not directly interacting with it.

I added the switch as both an action and outlet. My app started crashing. So I wondered if it was because the a control was added as both an action and outlet.

Answer (score 0):

The reason my app was crashing must have been an altogether different issue. It had nothing to do with the fact that I had added the switch as both an action and an outlet. I undid some of my recent changes and re added the switch, the app did not crash. The switch worked fine as both an action and an outlet.

TLDR: You can add a control and make it both an action and outlet. Perfectly legal.